Representation of nilpotent matrix
Every matrix is representable by Jordan Canonical form. It is a block diagonal form, where the diagonal blocks are given by $\lambda_i$ for distinct eigenvalues of the matrix, and if block is of size $l \times l$, then entries $a_{i,i+1} = 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq l-1$, and $a_{i,j} = 0$ if $j \notin\{i,i+1\}$. Now, suppose matrix is nilpotent and you are considering a matrix over some algebraically closed field (for example $\mathbb{C}$) (I here write $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and mean set of all $n \times n$ matrices over algebraically closed field, it is vector space, ring, Lie algebra, pick your poison). If $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ denotes the rank of a matrix $A \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$, then if $A$ is nilpotent, i.e. $A^n = 0$, by Binet-Cauchy theorem ($\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ for $A,B \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$) it follows $\det(A) = 0$, i.e. $A$ is not invertible, i.e. $\mathrm{rank}(A) < n$.Then matrix is nilpotent if and only if it has unique eigenvalue zero. Since zero is the unique eigenvalue, if we write nilpotent matrix $A$ in Jordan form, on the diagonal of every block is zero. Hence I would come to the following conclusion
Suppose $A \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$ is nilpotent matrix. Then $A$ can be represented by a matrix $B = \{b_{i,j}\} \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$ given by : $a_{i,i+1} = 1$ if $1 \leq i \leq \mathrm{rank}(A)$ and $a_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise.
Would I be right?

I presume at the end it was meant to be $b_{i,i+1}$ and $b_{i,j}$, but be as it may the matrices you describe are exactly the ones such that $\min{k\in\Bbb N,:, A^k=0}=1+\operatorname{rk}A$. For instance, that can't be done for $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\ 0&0&0&0\ 0&0&0&1\ 0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.
